# Differences between two models

Tags: percentages

Vladimir bought a car for $250000$ USD. He has two models to describe the car's loss of value.

Model 1: $y=250000-25000x$.

Model 2: $y=250000 \cdot 0.8^x$

where $y$ is the cost and $x$ is the amount of years that have passed since the purchase. What are the differences between the models?

I know that there is a difference when it comes to the $\%$ amount changes, but are there more key differences?

Comment: [Care to edit for readibility](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)?

Comment: The two models behave definitely for sufficiently large x. In particular the first one becomes negative whilst the later doesn't.

Comment: The shape and the speed of decrease. Look what happens for $x=10$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model-1 says, the value of the thing will go down 10% of the original value each year.

The model-2 says, the value of the thing will go down 20% of the current value each year.

It implies that,

The model-1 says, the value of the thing will be none after 10 years.

The model-2 says, the value of the thing will go down much faster than model-1 in the beginning, but will slow down later and the thing will not be a piece of junk in many years since its original value is so high.